# Bukkit - Check if player has custom item / problem with passing custom item object

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I created custom item with a custom recipe. My main class method:

```
  @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        // Life Crystal

        ItemStack lifecrystal = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND);
        ItemMeta meta = lifecrystal.getItemMeta();

        meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + "Life Crystal");

        ArrayList<String> lores = new ArrayList<>();
        lores.add("Increase your life points...");
        lores.add("...or just revive someone");

        meta.setLore(lores);
        lifecrystal.setItemMeta(meta);

        NamespacedKey key = new NamespacedKey(this, "life_crystal");

        ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(key, lifecrystal);

        recipe.shape(" E ", "LGL", "DID");

        recipe.setIngredient('E', Material.EMERALD);
        recipe.setIngredient('L', Material.LAPIS_LAZULI);
        recipe.setIngredient('G', Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        recipe.setIngredient('D', Material.DIAMOND);
        recipe.setIngredient('I', Material.GOLD_INGOT);

        Bukkit.addRecipe(recipe);

    }
```

Now, in other class I want to check if player has this my new item in the inventory

```
if(player.getInventory().contains('item')){

}
```

I don't know what to put in his 'item'. New itemstack or something else? These method are in two seperate files.

Answer (score 1):

The Inventory class offers many useful methods, one of them being [contains(ItemStack)](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html#contains-org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack-) that returns whether a player has a specific itemstack.

The issue now is how do we get our custom itemstack? Currently you create it locally inside the `onEnable()` method, we need to declare it a field so we can access it throughout the class. To give access for outside classes globally, we either need to declare the `lifecrystal` as `public` or make a getter, I choose the latter since outside classes does not need to edit our custom item.

```
private ItemStack lifecrystal; // declare globally

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    // initilize locally
    lifecrystal = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND);
    // rest of your itemstack code etc
}

// getter method for outside classes to access our itemstack
public ItemStack getLifeCrystal() {
    return lifecrystal;
}
```

Then in the second class:

```
public void anotherMethod() {
    // we can now access lifecrystal
    if(player.getInventory().contains(firstClass.getLifeCrystal())){ 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The `firstClass` being a reference to your first class, that you should be able to set up on your own, but feel free to ask questions!

I highly recommend reading about visibility of variables, access and encapsulation. It's a great tool in programming that you will use more than this time.
Simpletons are useful as well in some scenarios.

Comment: Note: it is worth keeping the references to your items in a `static` location, such as your main class or in a `ModItems` class so that you can reference them as needed (various vanilla classes serve this purpose for vanilla blocks/items/etc, so you can too).